# Functions on groups in pandas with range selected by label

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following Multiindex Pandas Seires:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

val = np.array([ 0.4, -0.6,  0.6,  0.5, -0.4,  0.2,  0.6,  1.2, -0.4])
inds = [(-1000, 1921.6), (-1000, 1922.3), (-1000, 1923.0), (-500, 1921.6),
       (-500, 1922.3), (-500, 1923.0), (-400, 1921.6), (-400, 1922.3),
       (-400, 1923.0)]
names = ['pp_delay', 'wavenumber']
example = pd.Series(val)
example.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(inds, names=names)
```

`example` should now look like

```
pp_delay  wavenumber
-1000     1921.6        0.4
          1922.3       -0.6
          1923.0        0.6
-500      1921.6        0.5
          1922.3       -0.4
          1923.0        0.2
-400      1921.6        0.6
          1922.3        1.2
          1923.0       -0.4
dtype: float64
```

I want to group example by `pp_delay` and select a **range within each group** using the `wavenumber` **index** and perform an operation on that subgroup. To clarify what I mean, I have a few examples.

Here is a position based solution.

```
example.groupby(level="pp_delay").nth(list(range(1,3))).groupby(level="pp_delay").sum()
```

this gives

```
pp_delay
-1000    0.0
-500    -0.2
-400     0.8
dtype: float64
```

Now the last to elements of each `pp_delay` group have been summed.

An alternative solution and more straight forward is to loop over the groups:

```
delays = example.index.levels[0]
res = np.zeros(delays.shape)
roi = slice(1922, 1924)
for i in range(3):
    res[i] = example[delays[i]][roi].sum()
res
```

gives

```
array([ 0. , -0.2,  0.8])
```

Anyhow I don't like it much ether because it doesn't fit well with the usual pandas style.

Now what I ideally would want something like:

```
example.groupby(level="pp_delay").loc[1922:1924].sum()
```

or maybe even something like

```
example[:, 1922:1924].sum()
```

But apparently pandas indexing doesn't work that way. Anybody got a better way?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd skip the `groupby`

```
example.unstack(0).ix[1922:1924].sum()

pp_delay
-1000    0.0
-500    -0.2
-400     0.8
dtype: float64
```